# Angular + SASS: why @use behaves wierdly when importing from node_modules?

Tags: angular, import, sass, node-modules

I'm having a weird behaviour with importing styles using `@use` in my Angular project.

Specifically, in my `styles.scss`

`@use "@angular/material" as mat;` WORKS PERFECTLY

while

`@use "ngx-popperjs" as ngx-popperjs;` ERRORS with "Can't find stylesheet to import".

I took a look under the hood of material SASS files and found out that they exposed stuff, using `@forward` in an `_index.scss` file placed exactly at `@angular/material/_index.scss`.

So I did the same with my `ngx-popperjs`.

And yet, I get the same error!

I saw online that many suggest to add `node_modules` in `stylePreprocessorOptions/include` in `angular.json`.

But why should I do that? Material works, means Popper must work as well!

The IDE resolves both the @use imports correctly.

What am I missing in popper??

**EDIT PROBABLY FOUND IN PACKAGE EXPORTS**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is exactly the `exports.sass` in the built @angular/material package.

Now I have to figure out how to do that when I **build** ngx-popperjs and it's done.

I will update the answer as soon as I discover the mistery :)

**UPDATE, SOLUTION FOUND!**

I looked at @angular/material sources and they simply have the sass exports declared in their lib package.json.
They actually have a more complicated management, but it's very simple when building your **angular libraries**.

You simply add your exports relative to your built package.json.

> Angular CLI will take care of merge-ing your exports with the generated ones

```
{
    "name": "ngx-popperjs",
    "version": "15.0.3",
    ...
    ...other stuff
    ...
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "sass": "./_index.scss"
        }
    }
}
```

So in my case when building I'll have `_index.scss` in the same dir as the `package.json`.

That's it! Hope it helps!